# Regex substitute file extension prefix placement doesn't work - replace matches

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I'm quite familiar with regex, but I'm not familiar with C++11's `std::regex_replace`. I spent like more than an hour trying to figure out how to replace a simple file extension, but nothing is working!

What I want to achieve is quite simple. I want to replace `myfile.pdf` with `myfile.txt`. So I wrote my regex to match files that end with `.pdf`:

```
std::regex regex("^.*\\.(pdf)$")
```

And following [a reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/) and following a [cheat-sheet](http://cpprocks.com/files/c++11-regex-cheatsheet.pdf), I want to see the prefix (whatever comes before a match), so I use:

```
std::string myStr = std::regex_replace(std::string("HiThere.pdf"), regex, std::string("$`"))
std::cout<< myStr <<std::endl;
```

And I get an empty string! This happens, although I get a match! To show that I'm getting a match, simply replace "$`" with "$1", and you'll see the first match replacing the whole string.

One side note, according to all references, $0 should show the whole string, but it doesn't!

All I want to achieve is to replace that match with ".txt". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think I see the problem... thank you. Let me try again.

Comment: Do you really need a regexp to replace `.pdf` by `.txt` at the end of a string?

Comment: @Holt It's the cleanest and shortest way to do it (that I know of).

Comment: Check if the string ends with `.pdf` and if so replace it with `.txt`, this will not be longer, probably be cleaner, and surely will be faster and more understandable for other people reading your code.

Comment: @Holt more understandable, maybe. But it'll definitely be multiple lines, unless I deliberately compress it so much and make it, again, not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$`" is going to be empty since you matched the entire input string.
It's a prefix to the *match*, not to the first backreference.

You can achieve your goal quite simply:

```
std::regex regex("^(.*)\\.pdf$");
const std::string myStr = std::regex_replace(
   "HiThere.pdf",
   regex,
   "$1.txt"
);
std::cout << myStr << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behaviour.  $` is the string *before* the match - but you matched the whole string!  (So $` is empty).

I also think you need to capture the `.*`, rather than the `.pdf` (you *know* what that is, after all!).  I think what you want is:

```
std::regex regex("^(.*)\\.pdf$")
std::string source("HiThere.pdf");
std::string myStr = std::regex_replace(source, regex, "$1.txt");
```

or even:

```
std::regex regex("\\.pdf$")
std::string source("HiThere.pdf");
std::string myStr = std::regex_replace(source, regex, ".txt");
```

Comment: Yup, you did - but I didn't see that until I pressed the submit button.